# Problems writing to image, then printing to SVG in Java

Tags: java, printing, svg, bufferedimage

As part of a program I am writing, I wish to print an image to SVG format.  I need it to be in SVG format, so that I can modify it using Adobe Illustrator later on.  As it stands, although I can draw a rectangle directly in the print method and export that successfully to SVG format.

When I draw the same rectangle in my `getTagCloud` method, the result (when printed to SVG) is a rectangle made up of a huge number of tiny rectangles.  I am at a loss as to why this might be so, though hopefully the answer will be blindingly obvious to someone reading this!

Ultimately, I need to print out more than just a rectangle but the exported "Group" in Illustrator is so large (containing as it does all these tiny rectangles of varying sizes) that I am unable to find the other objects I have drawn (as everything, no matter what colour I originally used, is rendered in black).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the relevant code.  I have not included the import statements as I don't have any problems compiling the code.

```
public class TagCloud {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Tag Cloud Generator");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    Toolkit tk = f.getToolkit();       
    Dimension wndSize = tk.getScreenSize();  


    f.setBounds(0, 0,   
                      wndSize.width, wndSize.height); 
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });

    f.add("Center",myPanel);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    myPanel.printTagCloud();

}


}

class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Printable{

private int squareX = 50;
private int squareY = 50;
private int squareW = 20;
private int squareH = 20;
private int x_offset = 30;
private int y_offset = 30;
private BufferedImage img = null;
private int defaultFontSize = 16;




public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    if (img == null){
        getTagCloudImage();

    } 
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 400);
    //g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void printTagCloud(){

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(aset);
    job.setPrintable(this);
    boolean ok = job.printDialog(aset);
    if (ok) {
        try {
             job.print(aset);
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {

        }
    }
}

public MyPanel() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    });
}

private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {

    int OFFSET = 1;
    if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
    } 
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1000,800);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
if (img == null){
    getTagCloudImage();
    } 
else{

    g.drawImage(img, x_offset, y_offset, null);
}

}


public void getTagCloudImage(){

img = new BufferedImage(250, 250, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 


Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

Rectangle r = new Rectangle (0,0,250,250);
g2.draw(r);
g2.setColor(Color.black);
g2.fill(r);
g2.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Which exactly printer have you used to print image to SVG? I would like to help you but first I need to recreate your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr.  I should have put that in, sorry.  I am printing to SVG format using PDFCreator.  I also downloaded a trial version of SVGMaker and tried that but it only seemed to produce an SVG file with an image (needing to be traced and expanded in Illustrator before being usable in the sense that SVG usually is).

Comment: You wrote "I can draw a rectangle directly in the print method and export that successfully to SVG format", but I don't see any drawing code in `print()` method. Drawing is delegated to the `getTagCloudImage()` method. Could you please post version of your  code that "exported succesfully to SVG format"? It would make it much easier.

Comment: @Piotr Hi again Piotr, I have added in those two lines of code into the print method and commented out the one where I draw the image.  With PDFCreator printing to SVG format, it exports perfectly as a rectangle, though it is black and not red.  If you need any more info, please let me know.

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to include `import` statements, in case a reader wishes to try compiling your code. Also, your code seems to have indentation problems - code inside classes should be indented, if only to make it easier for other people (e.g. readers here) to follow `:)`

Comment: @halfer Fair enough, I didn't think of that.  I won't make that mistake next time!

Comment: @Piotr Thank you very much for spending so long on this.   As you say, the use of BufferedImage seems to be causing problems, but the alternative is for me to do all my calculations in the print method, which I would rather not do, for multiple reasons.  I just tried an experiment there (albeit, I should have thought of that before). I called drawString from directly inside the print method and the exported text (to SVG via PDFCreator) was rendered using what seems like thousands of tiny rectangles.  So, the problem doesn't seem only to lie in the use of BufferedImage, at least for text.

Comment: @TrionaHowlett Yeah, that sounds weird... I guess SVG text element should be used (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) instead of many little rectangles. I will try it out when I come back home. But could you try to describe the idea of your application? Maybe we'll be able to find some alternative solution than using BufferedImage? Also, can we move our discussion to comments under my answer so not to clutter question thread too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help much without knowledge about Java `BufferedImage`,`Graphics`, `PrinterJob` and other related classes implementation. (You may start a bounty for this question to possibly draw attention of people having more intristic knowledge about java awt graphic stuff).

As you obviously must have noticed using `BufferedImage` (or not using it) is what makes a difference in SVG output. In the version that works you draw the rectangle directly on `Graphic` context provided to you as `print()` method argument and I believe that's how it was designed to be used by authors of `Printable` interface and printing framework.

In the second approach (that doesn't work correct) you first draw rectangle onto new  `BufferedImage` object and then draw this image on the provided `Graphic` context. So you do something much less straightforward than just drawing directly on the context. There is well known truth or intuition among developers that the less straightforward way do you use some API, the bigger is a chance that you do something unexpected by its authors :(.

My hypotesis is following: `BufferedImage` is (as you can deduce from its [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html))just a raster image, ie. grid of pixels. That's why svg file is populated with lots of small rectangles (trying to mimic pixels). The `Graphics` object provided by `draw()` method may be more abstract and operate on shapes rather than pixels, which is much more appropriate to be written to vector graphics formats like SVG. But that's just hypotesis.

The question is, do you really need to use `BufferedImage`? If I understand correctly, you want user to be able to edit rectangle on screen and when ready export it to SVG. Can't you just remember for example upper left corner and dimensions of rectangle edited by user and then use this data to recreate this rectangle directly on `Graphics` object provided by `print()`, like:

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
  throws PrinterException {
...
  g.fillRect(userRect.x,userRect.y,userRect.width,userRect.height);
...
}
```

?

(`userRect` is object of your own custom class which just stores data about image edited by user)

Comment: Sorry, Piotr.  I'm new to this site and didn't know I should be replying to you here.  I'm working on trying to somehow bring in the information I need from the getTagCloud method and drawing directly in the print method, as you suggested, rather than working off the BufferedImage.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: I tried drawing everything directly from the print method and some of the text exported perfectly, character by character, just as I wanted.  The smaller text, for some reason, exported again in "tiny rectangle" format.  Most importantly though, because I was no longer relying on the BufferedImage, the large black rectangle covering the entire image didn't export and so I was able to extract all the text, even if the export was long because of the rectangles.  So, thank you very much, Piotr, for your help.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I helped anything Triona, but I'm really glad that you found good enough solution :).